# Script help needed editing ini file

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to edit one line in an ini file. DeviceName=APPLE to DeviceName="The User Input". I have it almost there from bits and pieces across the internet. It works except the end result is my file jwalk.ini with the correct entry after user input but the ini file has been renamed to just .ini, no jwalk before ini. I must be missing something. The file jwalk.ini already will exist I just need to edit it with the new user input and leave the file named the same.

My Script:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Const OpenAsASCII = 0
Const CreateIfNotExist = True

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
' Open existing file for read access.
strInput = "c:\MyFolder\jwalk.ini"
Set objInput = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strInput, ForReading)

' Prompt for device name.
strDeviceName = InputBox("Enter devicename", "JWalk PC Name or Session Name")

' Specify the new file name.
strOutput = "c:\MyFolder\" & strComputer & ".ini"

' Create new file with write access.
Set objOutput = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strOutput, _
ForWriting, CreateIfNotExist, OpenAsASCII)

' Process input file.
Do Until objInput.AtEndOfStream
' Read next line of the input file.
strLine = objInput.ReadLine
' Search for line to be modified.
' Make search case insensitive.
If (InStr(LCase(strLine), "devicename=") > 0) Then
' Replace the line.
' You could also modify the line.
strLine = "devicename=" & strDeviceName
End If
' Write line to the output file.
objOutput.WriteLine strLine
Loop

' Clean up.
objInput.Close
objOutput.Close

' Delete the original file.
objFSO.DeleteFile(strInput)
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd have used `Option Explicit`, you'd have been told that

```
strOutput = "c:\MyFolder\" & strComputer & ".ini"
```

uses the undefined/uninitialized variable strComputer.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are passing "strComputer" as a var, but never set it's value:

```
' Specify the new file name.
strOutput = "c:\MyFolder\" & strComputer & ".ini"
```

If you are trying to get the computer name you could consider this:

```
' Specify the new file name.
strOutput = "c:\MyFolder\" & GetComputerName() & ".ini"

Function GetComputerName()
  Dim ob
  Set ob = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
  GetComputerName = ob.ComputerName
  Set ob = nothing 
End Function
```